# disable branch with "if constexpr" and SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, sfinae, if-constexpr

I want to enable/disable branches at compile time depending of whether a function can be called with certain arguments.
What has to go in the `if constexpr` condition?
I can get the result type via `std::result_of(decltype(add)(A, B))`, but how can I check, whether the result type is valid? (i.e. how to I convert this information to a `bool`?)

```
const auto add = [](const auto a, const auto b) { return a + b; };

const auto subtract = [](const auto a, const auto b) { return a - b; };

template <typename A, typename B>
void foo(A a, B b) {

  if constexpr ( /* can add(a, b) be called? */ ) {
    std::cout << "result of add: " << add(a, b) << std::endl;
  }

  if constexpr ( /* can subtract(a, b) be called? */ ) {
    std::cout << "result of subtract: " << subtract(a, b) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you check whether `add` or `subtract` can be called without the `constexpr` restriction?

Comment: It does not have to be a `constexpr`, but the check should be compile time. `decltype(add(a, b))` gives a substitution error for invalid combinations of types. I want to use that error as the condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to make your lambdas SFINAE-friendly.

```
#define RETURNS(...)\
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__))\
  ->decltype(__VA_ARGS__)\
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

const auto add = [](const auto a, const auto b) RETURNS( a + b );

const auto subtract = [](const auto a, const auto b) RETURNS( a - b );
```

Now add and subract can be tested in a SFINAE context.

```
namespace details {
  template<class, class, class...>
  struct can_invoke:std::false_type {};
  template<class F, class...Args>
  struct can_invoke<F, std::void_t< std::result_of_t< F&&(Args&&...) > >, Args... >:
    std::true_type
  {};
}
template<class F, class...Args>
using can_invoke_t = details::can_invoke<F, Args...>;

template<class F, class...Args>
constexpr can_invoke_t< F, Args... >
can_invoke( F&&, Args&&... ){ return {}; }
```

and we are ready:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
void foo(A a, B b) {

  if constexpr ( can_invoke( add, a, b ) ) {
    std::cout << "result of add: " << add(a, b) << std::endl;
  }

  if constexpr ( can_invoke( subtract, a, b ) {
    std::cout << "result of subtract: " << subtract(a, b) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

this is [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14); in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) it is more awkward, in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) more elegant as they already have a can invoke type trait (which handles a few more corner cases; however, it also expects you to call `add` with `std::invoke`).

---

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) I sort of like this trick:

```
template<class F>
constexpr auto invoke_test( F&& ) {
  return [](auto&&...args) ->
  can_invoke_t<F, decltype(args)...>
  { return {}; };
}

template <typename A, typename B>
void foo(A a, B b) {

  if constexpr ( invoke_test( add )( a, b ) ) {
    std::cout << "result of add: " << add(a, b) << std::endl;
  }

  if constexpr ( invoke_test( subtract )( a, b ) {
    std::cout << "result of subtract: " << subtract(a, b) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

where `invoke_test` takes a callable, and returns a callable whose only job is to answer "the original callable be invoked with the args you passed me".

Comment: As an aside, `invoke_test` can be extended to a compile-time optional `Maybe`, but I'm uncertain how well `if constexpr` supports side-effects-only-if-true.  Probably not well.  ;)

Comment: Where you say is C++14, well, it can`t be, because you use if constexpr and that is C++17.

Answer (score 3):

You can put SFINAE to the return type and let function overloading tell whether a call can be made. A helper function `can_be_called` can be implemented as following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class Func, class... Args>
constexpr auto
can_be_called(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(
            (std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
            , bool{}))
{ return true; }

struct Dummy {
    template<class T> constexpr Dummy(T&&) {}
};

template<class... Args>
constexpr bool 
can_be_called(Dummy, Args&&...) { return false; }

// test
#include <iostream>
void foo(int, int) {}

struct A{};

int main() {
    if constexpr( can_be_called(foo, 1, 2) ) {
        std::cout << "OK\n";
    }

    if constexpr ( !can_be_called(foo, A{}, 2) ) {
        std::cout << "NO\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: When did passing a lambda to `...` become defined behaviour?

Comment: @Yakk I switch to an implicit conversion to the first parameter. Please check whether it's ok now ?

Comment: @liliscent Now a problem is that you are copying the types.  If the lambda or the arguments are not constexpr-copyable, the code breaks.  Use universal references and perfect forwarding.